# Hibernate batch_size best value

Tags: hibernate

Can anybody advice me how to choose the best value for `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`? 

If memory and CPU is not a problem is it ok to use a value like 500.

EDIT:
In [this chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html) it says to use a value between 10 and 50. But not mention a reason. Can anybody assume reason for this limitation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hibernate documentation recommends a value between 5 and 30. The best value is entirely dependent on your app, your data, your database. Try various values and measure the performance of each one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. In [this chapter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch04.html) it says to use a value between 10 and 50. But not mention a reason. Do you mean that document?

Comment: I read the previous version of the documentation, for Hibernate 3.6. It looks like they did another benchmark and refined their numbers (which stay in the same order of magnitude).

Answer (score 0):

Max is 50. Min is 10. for 10K records 50 is good