# JPA batch inserts does not improve performance

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I would like to improve the performance of my postgresql inserts with JPA batch inserts.

I'm using :

- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.1.3.RELEASE
- postgresql 42.2.5 (jdbc driver).
- Database is PostgreSQL 9.6.2

I have managed to activate JPA's batch inserts, but performance has not improved at all.

- I use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` in my entities
- I use `reWriteBatchedInserts=true` in my jdbc connexion string
- I set the following properties :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

- I use the saveAll(collection) method
- I tried to flush and clean my entityManager after each batch
- I tried with a batch size of 100 and 1000, flushing for each batch, with no noticeable change.

I can see in the logs that hibernate does use batch inserts but am unsure if my database does (I'm trying to fetch the logs, folder permission is pending).

```java
@Service
@Configuration
@Transactional
public class SecteurGeographiqueServiceImpl implements SecteurGeographiqueService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecteurGeographiqueServiceImpl.class);

@Value("${spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}")
private int batchSize;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private SecteurGeographiqueRepository secteurGeographiqueRepository;

    @Override
    public List<SecteurGeographique> saveAllSecteurGeographiquesISOs(List<SecteurGeographique> listSecteurGeographiques) {
    logger.warn("BATCH SIZE : " + this.batchSize);
    final List<SecteurGeographique> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<SecteurGeographique> savedList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listSecteurGeographiques.size(); i++) {
        if ((i % this.batchSize) == 0) {
            savedList.addAll(this.secteurGeographiqueRepository.saveAll(tempList));
            tempList.clear();
            this.entityManager.flush();
            this.entityManager.clear();
        }
        tempList.add(listSecteurGeographiques.get(i));
    }
    savedList.addAll(this.secteurGeographiqueRepository.saveAll(tempList));
    tempList.clear();
    this.entityManager.flush();
    this.entityManager.clear();
    return savedList;
    }

}

...

@Entity
public class SecteurGeographique {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long id;
...
```

My repository implementation is :

```
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository<SecteurGeographique, Long>
```

**application.properties** (connection part) :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://xx.xx.xx.xx:5432/bddname?reWriteBatchedInserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

And **in the logs** after my 16073 entities are inserted (this test does not include flushing) :

```
13:31:40.882 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
    15721506 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    121091067 nanoseconds spent preparing 16074 JDBC statements;
    240144821872 nanoseconds spent executing 16073 JDBC statements;
    3778202166 nanoseconds spent executing 161 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    4012929596 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 16073 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Note that this is just one table, with no constraint / foreign key. Just flat basic data in a table, nothing fancy.

From the logs ot does look like there is a problem :

```
240144821872 nanoseconds spent executing <b>16073 JDBC statements</b>;
3778202166 nanoseconds spent executing 161 JDBC batches;
```

Shouldn't it be "executing **161** JDBC statements" if everything is in the batches ?

**Tests with flushes, and batch sizes 100 then 1000 :**

```
15:32:17.612 [restartedMain] WARN  f.g.j.a.r.s.i.SecteurGeographiqueServiceImpl - BATCH SIZE : 100
15:36:46.206 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
    15416324 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    105369002 nanoseconds spent preparing 16234 JDBC statements;
    262388696401 nanoseconds spent executing 16073 JDBC statements;
    3669253410 nanoseconds spent executing 161 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    3956493726 nanoseconds spent executing 161 flushes (flushing a total of 16073 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}

15:43:54.155 [restartedMain] WARN  f.g.j.a.r.s.i.SecteurGeographiqueServiceImpl - BATCH SIZE : 1000
15:48:22.335 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
    15676227 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    111370586 nanoseconds spent preparing 16090 JDBC statements;
    265089247563 nanoseconds spent executing 16073 JDBC statements;
    599946208 nanoseconds spent executing 17 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    866452023 nanoseconds spent executing 17 flushes (flushing a total of 16073 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

Each time I get a 4min 30sec execution time. It feels enormous for batch inserts.
What am I missing / misinterpreting ?

Comment: What is the implementation of your repository ?

Comment: @Zorglube I use org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository<SecteurGeographique, Long>. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: If you whant your insert to go faster, espetialiy for 16073 insert, you better use native parametrised SQL Query : `Insert Into SecteurGeographique (id, ...) Values( :id, ...)`.

Comment: If you wanna go a bit more fast, get the position of `SecteurGeographique_PK` to forge your `id` during the insert, and push the new position of `SecteurGeographique_PK` after insert.

Comment: @Zorglube Yes I understand both of these, but my question is really about understanding what is happening. Most people using the solution I used witness very noticeable performance gains, whereas I don't have any.

Comment: Search into Spring Data.

Comment: Probably the 'Batch' is doing the save one by one.

Comment: This is the feeling I get but the logs confirm the 161 batch inserts. Didn't find more info from Spring Data JPA.

Comment: You should investigate more. From my side I'm able to do 700K insert, througt spring, and it need only ~2min.

Comment: Batches is the number of jdbc statements that might (depending on your JDBC driver) be merged into a single insert. If you don't start cleaning your `Entitymanager` i.e. your first level cache hibernate will do dirty checks for each entity in the first level cache (hence the importance of `flush` and `clear` when doing batch processing. The clear will remove the entities from the first level cache and thus will not be dirty checked and will improve performance. Trying to save all of them in 1 go will lead to performance issues.

Comment: @M.Deinum : This is not it. I did say I tried flushing. I will update the question and code so this misunderstanding is out of the way, or at least someone can tell me if I'm flushing wrong. Also see my own anwser below, with added flushing and cleaning.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Thanks for the explanation of the importance of flushing though.

Comment: @johimi I am using the same code for batch updates/inserts as mentioned above, but still I am getting 0 JDBC batches. I have added all the necessary configs for hibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying a batch size of 1000 with a postgresql server on localhost (https://gareth.flowers/postgresql-portable/ v10.1.1), the execution runs **under 3 seconds**. So it seems the code or configuration is not to blame here.

Unfortunately I cannot investigate why it was taking so much time on the remote postgresql (hosted on an AWS), but I can only conclude this was a network or database issue.

As of today I cannot access postgresql remote logs, but if you have any advice on what to look for on the postgresql instance, I'm all ears.

**Logs with batching (1000) and flush+clean :**

```
16:20:52.360 [restartedMain] WARN  f.g.j.a.r.s.i.SecteurGeographiqueServiceImpl - BATCH SIZE : 1000
16:20:54.844 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
    523125 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    44649191 nanoseconds spent preparing 16090 JDBC statements;
    1311557995 nanoseconds spent executing 16073 JDBC statements;
    204225325 nanoseconds spent executing 17 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    381230968 nanoseconds spent executing 17 flushes (flushing a total of 16073 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

**Logs WITHOUT batching, flush or clean :**

```
16:57:34.426 [restartedMain] INFO  o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener - Session Metrics {
    725069 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    55763008 nanoseconds spent preparing 32146 JDBC statements;
    2816525053 nanoseconds spent executing 32146 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    1796451447 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 16073 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

This comparison shows a 46% gain in the overall JDBC statements execution time.

Comment: Pay attention to not put a batch_size too high
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789052/hibernate-batch-size-best-value
Should be <100